# Does VSCode have an option to "Create tests" for a java class?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, I have the ability to "[Create tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html)" for a Java class.

- Does VS Code have anything similar? Any extension or in-built functionality.
- If not, what would be the steps I should follow to create such an option for my use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not. I have tried 'Junit Testfile Generator' extension, but it's rough.

Comment: What is the issue with it?

Comment: it's coarse. And you can make a try of it.

Answer (score 7):

As of today VSCode has in-built action to generate test.

You have to open Command Palette and select "Source Action". Then you'll be promted with window containing some options and one of them will be "Generate Tests".

Comment: This is accurate as of v1.79.0 of VSCode.